# What is the reason to turn sync functions into async in a promise chain in Bluebird?

Tags: bluebird

Bluebird's documentation and external posts mention the differences between asynchronous errors and synchronous errors, and have some functions to help coral all these into async errors (e.g., `Promise.try` and `Promise.method`)? This seems to be because (among other things) error handling is different for the two (sync is caught with a `try`/`catch`, while async is caught with a `.catch`).

But don't `then` statements accept synchronous functions (`throws` are considered rejects, and `return` as resolves) or promises (with the standard `reject`/`resolve`) in any one after the first method of a series of chained functions? (e.g., in a().then(b).then(c).catch(function(e){}) - the b/c parts). The final `.catch` seems to collect errors from either a reject in a promise or a throw from sync code.

So is the main purpose of these additional Bluebird functions for the first part of the callback chain only? Or is there some other reason to turn synchronous code into a promise.

Comment: Once the code is in a Bluebird `.then()` handler, it's already async and already throw-safe.  The Bluebird helpers are for code that is not yet in a `.then()` handler.  They are helpers to automatically wrap that code for you to make it throw safe and to make any early synchronous return also be async so that it is compatible with other async code paths.  You do not want a function that is sometimes synchronous and sometimes async.  If it can ever be async, then any synchronous paths should be made async also to give a consistent async programming interface to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see a pretty basic example of some case where we have an asynchronous and a synchronous path in a certain piece of code:

```
var expiryTime = 1457155658238;
var cachedCopy = 'abcdefghijk';

var p = Date.now() > expiryDate ? getNewCopy() : cachedCopy;

p.then(function (information) {
  // do something
});
```

Notice the issue here? Since `cachedCopy` is not a promise, it will throw an error if the condition follows down this path. Because of this, we need to wrap `cachedCopy` into a promise:

```
var p = Date.now() > expiryDate ? getNewCopy() : Promise.resolve(cachedCopy);
```

However, this can get tedious if we have to do this for multiple code paths. You might wonder why we don't simply just put this into a function and then call `Promise.resolve` on the return value to wrap it into a promise. Take this code:

```
var expiryTime = 1457155658238;
var cachedCopy = 'abcdefghijk';
var canGetNewCopy = false;

function getInfo() {
  if (Date.now() < expiryDate) return cachedCopy;
  if (canGetNewCopy) return getNewCopy();
  throw new Error('fail!');
}

Promise.resolve(getInfo()).then(function (information) {
  // do something
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('an error occured!');
  cleanup();
});
```

What will happen if it is past the expiry date? Because `getInfo()` will throw an error, the cleanup code will not run.

Bluebird's `Promise.try` fixes all of these issues. By catching errors thrown inside the function passed, as well as wrapping values into a promise if they are returned synchronously, this saves a lot of code wrapping and reduces the chance of subtle errors in your code. Now our example looks something like this:

```
var expiryTime = 1457155658238;
var cachedCopy = 'abcdefghijk';
var canGetNewCopy = false;

Promise.try(function () {
  if (Date.now() < expiryDate) return cachedCopy;
  if (canGetNewCopy) return getNewCopy();
  throw new Error('fail!');
}).then(function (information) {
  // do something
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('an error occured!');
  cleanup();
});
```

Now if an error is thrown inside the `Promise.try` callback, the returned promise will be rejected and hence the cleanup code will run. `Promise.method` also exists in Bluebird for similar reasons (to ensure that a function in an API always return a promise).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Am I right then that it's primarily (always?) useful for the first statement in a series of thens, as you need the first clause to be a promise - but latter ones can be either promises or sync code that `returns`/`throws`?

Comment: @user1985427 pretty much so -- this is especially important in APIs where you don't know how others will be using your code.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much. One final question. I noticed that the native `Promise.all` will automatically wrap a function in `Promise.resolve` if it's not a promise, so is another potential reason to use this where certain APIs require a promise and don't reject on a `throw` (e.g., Bluebird seems to reject on a throw, but the native code doesn't seem to).